# Syntax error in JSON path in argument 2 to function 'json_set' at position 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, wordpress

**while update record in json it shown me " Syntax error in JSON path in argument 2 to function 'json_set' at position 1"**

my query is

```
UPDATE wp_users 
SET stress_email_details = JSON_SET(stress_email_details, 2021 ,1) 
where id = 349
```

i wrote in wordpress like

```
$wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $usersTable SET stress_email_details = JSON_SET(stress_email_details, '$.$b' ,'$.$currentWeek->week') where id = $activeUser->ID",0));
```

```
my desired output like.
i have empty stress_email_details field.
when i update row it will store 
likes  {'2021' : 1}
and next when i update again it will update like

{2021 : 1 , 2021: 2 }  or {2021 : {1,2,3,...}} or {2021 : {1,2,3,...}, 2022 : {1,2,3,...}}
i just want to store 2021 is year and 1 is week of year.
```

Comment: As of [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html): `JSON_SET(json_doc, path, val[, path, val] ...)`, so `2021` is definitely not a valid json path. Please, provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Would it help to dump the query first?

Comment: @astentx i updated my quetion